# Spring Security: Authorization Server: Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I had a working autherization server and updated spring boot starter and spring security dependancies to `2.3.3.RELEASE`, `5.0.6.RELEASE`

Related Dependancies,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for OAuth 2.0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have 3 main configuration classes,

1. Authorization Server Configuration: AuthServerConfig.java

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableAuthorizationServer
   public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

     @Autowired
     private DataSource dataSource;

     @Override
     public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
       clients.jdbc(dataSource);//.passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
     }

     @Override
     public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
      }
   }
   ```
2. Web Security Configuration: WebSecurityConfig.java

   ```
   @Configuration
   @Order(-20)
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       // @formatter:off
       http.requestMatchers()       
           .and()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/login", "/index.html", "/", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**")
               .permitAll()
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
           .and().
               formLogin()
               .loginPage("/login")
               .permitAll()
            .and()
               .csrf().disable();
       // @formatter:on
   }

   @Bean
   public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
       DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
         = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
       authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
       authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
       return authProvider;
   }



   @Override
   protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
   }

   }
   ```
3. Application Configuration: AuthApplication.java

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @Controller
   @EnableResourceServer
   @SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
   public class AuthApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
   }

   @RequestMapping("/user")
   @ResponseBody
   public Principal user(Principal user) {
       return user;
   }

   @Override
   public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
       registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
   }

   }
   ```

Here are the logs:

```
    2018-07-15 00:13:52.516 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-07-15 00:13:52.516 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-07-15 00:13:52.516 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-07-15 00:13:52.516 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/login'
2018-07-15 00:13:52.516 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/index.html'
2018-07-15 00:13:52.516 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/'
2018-07-15 00:13:52.517 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/css/**'
2018-07-15 00:13:52.517 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/images/**'
2018-07-15 00:13:52.517 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/js/**'
2018-07-15 00:13:52.517 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/authorize; Attributes: [authenticated]
2018-07-15 00:13:52.517 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@75385b60: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2018-07-15 00:13:52.517 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@2d4d1397, returned: -1
2018-07-15 00:13:52.518 DEBUG 33306 --- [io-9980-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_141]
```

This issue is addressed here.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/993
But this doesn't apply to the versions I am using,

According to the related resources I read, this happens due the order in authentication filters.

Pages Views seems to be taking this loop.

[/login] -> [/oauth_access]->[/login] -> [/login]

During the initial login, I can see Authentication succeeds, But when it comes to **/oauth/authorize** it fails. Above logs are related to  **/oauth/authorize**

Comment: Why does everyone disable CSRF protection - it's like you want malicious websites to take advantage...

Comment: @biris I am now randomly changing stuff to see if things work. Yes it's very important in production

Comment: did you ever figure this out?